# prepare stmt is not working

Tags: mysql, database-design, stored-procedures

set @sqlt = concat("select", @rowname_date," from  `syslog_data`.`syslogs_index_1` ");
prepare stmt from @sqlt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

gives me a eeror 1064 in the prepare statement?
Any advise please.
Thanks

Comment: What is in `@rowname_date`? Please post the result of `SELECT @rowname_date;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a valid column name or a properly escaped literal in `@rowname_date` and you don't have leading spaces in it then you have to have a space after `SELECT` clause

```
set @sqlt = concat("select", @rowname_date," from syslog_data.syslogs_index_1 ");
                         ^^
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61dab/1)** demo

Comment: @Gordon Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?